# create a new column using previous row of other column consider a duplicate as well as a based on group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I hope someone can help me with this ,stuck with the code for last three days

I have the following dataframe:

```
 Y B C D  X1 X1_Previous  X2 X2_previous
Y1 a b c   1          NA   1          NA
Y2 a b c   2           1   1           1
Y3 a b c   3           2   1           1
Y1 z y x   1          NA   1          NA
Y3 z y x   2           1   2           1
Y1 b f c   1          NA   1          NA
```

I have a column Y where only three values will be there Y1,Y2 and Y3 B,C,D column will be same for Y1,Y2 and Y3,the Y1,Y2,Y3 will have different set of B,C,D For Y1 X1 column is 1,then for Y2 the X1_previous column has to be 1,Y2 is 1 then X1_previous will be 1 for Y3 value

I used df.duplicated function for column B,C and D and for comparing with previous value used shift but i don't know how to compare with y1,y2, and y3 check duplicated and print previous value at same time can someone help me to solve this ?

Comment: Can you please show the sample output you want?

Comment: The problem is solved.Thanks for your reply